# Can i line break in kendo chart labels template?

Tags: c#, kendo-asp.net-mvc

```
.Series(series =>
    {
        series.Pie(
            model => model.REVENUE,
            model => model.SERVICE_NAME)
            .Labels(labels => labels
                .Template("#= category #: \n #= kendo.format(\'{0:n}\', value)#")
                .Background("transparent")
                .Visible(true)
            )
            .StartAngle(150);
    })
```

[image]

Can i add line break in kendo labels template ?

Thanks

Comment: ' \n 'not working for me T T

Comment: possible duplicate of [Line break in category label of kendo-ui chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247577/line-break-in-category-label-of-kendo-ui-chart)